# C# Firebase get timestamp from database

Tags: c#, wpf, firebase, timestamp

I have created a WPF form in c# that works alongside firebase to send messages. I would like to send a request for a timestamp to firebase and then get a response back. I have imported the following.

```
using Firebase.Storage;
using FireSharp.Config;
using FireSharp.Interfaces;
using FireSharp.Response;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
```

And initialized the following

```
  static string basePath = Properties.Settings.Default.FirebaseAppUri;
    static string storagePath = Properties.Settings.Default.FirebaseStorage;


    //Setup Firebase path and access rights
    IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
    {
        AuthSecret = Properties.Settings.Default.NormalFireKey,
        BasePath = basePath
    };

    IFirebaseClient client;
```

I have tried the following code

```
   public async void generateTimeStampAsync()
    {
        FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetTaskAsync($"ServerValue/TIMESTAMP");
        Person  person = response.ResultAs<Person>();
        MessageBox.Show(person.ToString());
    }
}
```

But the program simply receives a null. Any adfvice on how to do this in c# for wpf application?

Comment: Because you're casting to the wrong object.  You're asking for a timestamp, I don't know what type that will be exactly. I would guess datetime.  It's not going to be a person though. If you stick a breakpoint on that line after the await. When it's hit, are you getting a datetime or something similar back in your response?

Comment: Hi sorry Person is a DateTime Object, i simply used an existing file i had andd edited it

Comment: How would you suggest getting a timestamp from firebase from C#. If i can get tht right i am sorted

Comment: I also investigated the firestore library but it is so badly documentated i can't work out how to implement it for what i need